# Simplified version of Drew Wilson's autosuggest?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [Drew Wilson's autosuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin).

It's working as it's supposed to. However, I would like to simplify it. I like the way it shows the results and the way it searches, but I really don't need the multiple selection option - just one. I would also like to keep the original input field formatting. I removed all the unneccesary formatting in the css file but I really don't know what to with the jquery js file.

Has anyone simplified it yet or knows a source that I could use?  I've been searching for ages but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my answer isn't too too specific - I *just* answered a questions that is pretty much the same. Please check it out, I think it'll be helpful to you...

- [Chosen's multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774588/chosens-multiple-select/8775453#8775453)

Comment: Thank you. i have checked them but all of them are multiple selections.  I don't want that. I want only one line to select without the x(delete button).  Just want to select it as a simple text.

Comment: Perhaps Chosen would work for you? It also supports single selections.

Comment: Also the tokeninput jQuery plugin that I reference in my post looks to be very customizable - if you needed to go down that route of 'modding' a library to get the exact functionality you are looking for I'd suggest 'building up' from something like that library rather than 'ripping out'.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do that. Thank you again.